# raspberry pi python increasing cpu usage

Tags: python, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi

I have the following python program on a raspberry pi:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import glob
import os.path
from pathlib2 import Path
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import socket
from time import gmtime, strftime
import socket
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
import re

#############################lcd screen####################
lcd_rs = 25
lcd_en = 24
lcd_d4 = 23
lcd_d5 = 17
lcd_d6 = 18
lcd_d7 = 22
lcd_backlight = 4

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)


#############################temp reader########################
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
#divice_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-0115818f20ff')[0]
#device_file = divice_folder + '/w1_slave'

def temp_sen():
        for folder in os.listdir(base_dir):
                #print folder
                if re.match(r'[^w1_bus]', folder):
                        divice_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + folder)[0]
                        print divice_folder
                        device_file = divice_folder + '/w1_slave'
                        print device_file
                        return device_file
thefile = temp_sen()
def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(thefile, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string =  lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        #temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        #temp_c_str = "{:.3f}".format(temp_c)
        #temp_f_str = "{:.3f}".format(temp_f)
                #temp_c_str = str(round(temp_c, 1))
                #temp_f_str = str(round(temp_f, 1))
        #temps = 'C: ' + temp_c_str + '\n\rF: ' + temp_f_str
        return temp_c


####################keypad###########################
class keypad():
    KEYPAD = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    ["*",0,"#"]
    ]
    ROW = [21,6,13,19]
    COLUMN = [12,16,20]

    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM);
    def getKey(self):
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.LOW)

        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
            GPIO.setup(self.ROW[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

        rowVal = -1
        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
            tmpRead = GPIO.input(self.ROW[i])
            if tmpRead == 0:
                rowVal = i

        if (rowVal < 0) or (rowVal > 3):
            self.exit()
            return
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

        GPIO.setup(self.ROW[rowVal], GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.ROW[rowVal], GPIO.HIGH)

        colVal = -1
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            tmpRead = GPIO.input(self.COLUMN[j])
            if tmpRead == 1:
                colVal = j

        if (colVal < 0) or (colVal > 2):
            self.exit()
            return

        self.exit()
        return self.KEYPAD[rowVal][colVal]

    def exit(self):
        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
            GPIO.setup(self.ROW[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.ROW[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#######################logfile###########################
def log_file():
    if temp_con.t != 0:
                DTnow = str(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'))
                today = str(datetime.now().date())
                tmp = read_temp()
                temp = str(tmp)
                myfile = Path("/home/pi/TempLog/" + today + ".txt")
                if myfile.is_file:
                        log = open(str(myfile), "a")
                        log.write(DTnow + " " + temp + "C" + "\n")
                else:
                        log = open(str(myfile),"a+")
                        log.write(DTnow + " " + temp + "C" + "\n")
                threading.Timer(2, log_file).start()
#########################relay control###################
relay_pin = 27
def on():
    GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
def off():
    GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)        
######temp controler############
class temp_con:
    def __init__(self):
        self._t = 0

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    @t.setter
    def t(self, value):     
        self._t = value

#############physical inputs################
def phys_in():
        while True:
                kp = keypad()   
                list = ['']
                digit = None
                while True:
                    digit = kp.getKey()
                    if digit != None and digit != '*' and digit != '#':
                        list.append(str(digit))
                        time.sleep(.5)
                        digit = None
                    elif digit == '*':
                        while True:
                                        log_file()
                            stop = kp.getKey()
                            temp_con.t = int(''.join(list))
                            Rtemp = str(read_temp())
                            if read_temp() <= temp_con.t and stop != '#':
                                #time.sleep(1)
                                #lcd.clear()

                                print "relay activated!"
                                #lcd.message("relay activated!")

                                time.sleep(.5)
                                lcd.clear()

                                lcd.message(Rtemp)

                                print Rtemp
                                on()

                            elif read_temp() >= temp_con.t and stop != '#':
                                #time.sleep(1)
                                #lcd.clear()

                                print "relay deactivated!"
                                #lcd.message("relay deactivated!")
                                time.sleep(.5)
                                                lcd.clear()

                                                lcd.message(Rtemp)

                                                print Rtemp
                                    off()

                                elif stop == '#':
                                    temp_con.t = 0
                                    del list[:]
                                    lcd.clear()

                                    print "oven is now off!"
                                    lcd.message("oven is now off!")

                                    off()
                                    digit = None
                                    stop = None
                                    break   

######################main#########################
if __name__ == '__main__':
        phys_in()
```

As this program runs it becomes increasingly slower.

the basic flow is use inputs a temperature on a keypad and then hits the '*' key. the program then reads from a temperature sensor and compares the 2 numbers and responds acording to weather the sensor tempurature is higher or lower than the input temperature. if the  '#' key is pressed the input temperature is set to 0 and everything is reset to default.

the program is set to run at boot and starts out taking about 4 seconds to complete but after about 10 minutes it takes over 10 seconds and continues to degrade.

I suspect a memory leak some where but I am unable to locate it. can anyone spot the problem?

Edit: forgot to mention this is on a raspberry pi. upon checking processes with top i have discovered that memory usage is not increasing but cpu usage is. has gone from 2% to almost 30% in 2. minutes.

Edit2: this is the result of cProfile:

541055 function calls in 813.851 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

```
    1    0.000    0.000  813.851  813.851 <string>:1(<module>)

  180    0.005    0.000    0.868    0.005 Adafruit_CharLCD.py:169(clear)

  180    0.021    0.000    1.758    0.010 Adafruit_CharLCD.py:234(message)

 1225    0.112    0.000    2.051    0.002 Adafruit_CharLCD.py:261(write8)

 8755    1.243    0.000    1.997    0.000 Adafruit_CharLCD.py:296(_delay_microseconds)

 2450    0.113    0.000    0.368    0.000 Adafruit_CharLCD.py:302(_pulse_enable)

18375    0.154    0.000    0.229    0.000 GPIO.py:190(output)

 2450    0.119    0.000    0.261    0.000 GPIO.py:81(output_pins)

 5723    0.331    0.000    0.659    0.000 TempManualControlsOven.py:124(exit)

  181    0.062    0.000  198.064    1.094 TempManualControlsOven.py:130(log_file)

  180    0.005    0.000    0.011    0.000 TempManualControlsOven.py:149(off)
    1    0.254    0.254  813.851  813.851 TempManualControlsOven.py:166(phys_in)

  723    0.030    0.000  789.489    1.092 TempManualControlsOven.py:52(read_temp_raw)

  723    0.068    0.000  789.574    1.092 TempManualControlsOven.py:57(read_temp)

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TempManualControlsOven.py:86(__init__)

 5723    0.534    0.000    1.617    0.000 TempManualControlsOven.py:88(getKey)

  181    0.010    0.000    0.113    0.001 pathlib2.py:1172(__new__)

  181    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 pathlib2.py:1182(_init)

  181    0.038    0.000    0.064    0.000 pathlib2.py:177(parse_parts)

  181    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 pathlib2.py:413(splitroot)

  181    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 pathlib2.py:58(_py2_fsencode)

  181    0.016    0.000    0.091    0.001 pathlib2.py:797(_parse_args)

  181    0.009    0.000    0.101    0.001 pathlib2.py:826(_from_parts)

  181    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 pathlib2.py:849(_format_parsed_parts)

  181    0.015    0.000    0.022    0.000 pathlib2.py:866(__str__)

  181    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:1008(daemon)

  181    0.006    0.000    0.174    0.001 threading.py:1046(Timer)

  181    0.009    0.000    0.168    0.001 threading.py:1067(__init__)

  181    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 threading.py:1152(currentThread)

  543    0.018    0.000    0.089    0.000 threading.py:242(Condition)

  543    0.064    0.000    0.071    0.000 threading.py:260(__init__)

  180    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 threading.py:294(_release_save)

  180    0.002    0.000    0.006    0.000 threading.py:297(_acquire_restore)

  180    0.003    0.000    0.013    0.000 threading.py:300(_is_owned)

  180    0.016    0.000    0.127    0.001 threading.py:309(wait)

  362    0.006    0.000    0.089    0.000 threading.py:542(Event)

  362    0.013    0.000    0.083    0.000 threading.py:561(__init__)

  181    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 threading.py:570(isSet)

 1086    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 threading.py:59(__init__)

  181    0.008    0.000    0.141    0.001 threading.py:603(wait)

  181    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 threading.py:629(_newname)

  361    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 threading.py:64(_note)

  181    0.022    0.000    0.124    0.001 threading.py:656(__init__)

  181    0.006    0.000    0.012    0.000 threading.py:709(_set_daemon)

  181    0.019    0.000    0.220    0.001 threading.py:726(start)

22901    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 {RPi._GPIO.input}

35727    0.130    0.000    0.130    0.000 {RPi._GPIO.output}

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {RPi._GPIO.setmode}

80314    0.517    0.000    0.517    0.000 {RPi._GPIO.setup}

  181    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x2d4c48}

  362    0.032    0.000    0.032    0.000 {built-in method now}

  181    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {hasattr}

  724    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {intern}

  543    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {isinstance}

 2450    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {iter}

28983    0.039    0.000    0.039    0.000 {len}

  901    0.106    0.000    0.106    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}

 1268    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}

  722    0.107    0.000    0.107    0.000 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}

  181    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

  722    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}

 2450    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}

  362    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}

  181    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'lstrip' of 'str' objects}

  723  789.152    1.091  789.152    1.091 {method 'readlines' of 'file' objects}

  361    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}

  181    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reverse' of 'list' objects}

  181    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}

  181    0.029    0.000    0.029    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}

  722    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}

  181    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}

  904    0.261    0.000    0.261    0.000 {open}

 1045    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {ord}

28621    0.091    0.000    0.091    0.000 {range}

  723    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {thread.allocate_lock}

  181    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {thread.get_ident}

  181    0.059    0.000    0.059    0.000 {thread.start_new_thread}

  182   19.033    0.105   19.033    0.105 {time.sleep}
```

273246    0.754    0.000    0.754    0.000 {time.time}

the only thing jumping out at me is readlines.

Comment: [This article](http://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/) might help...

Comment: What makes you think that the reduced performance is caused by a memory leak?

Comment: ok memory usage isn't increasing(discovered top on my raspberry pi) so i guess its not that but cpu usage is going up. it went from 2% to 20% in 2 minutes.

Comment: Wrap your code in [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and let it run for some time. ^c it after some time and see in what function(s) the cpu cycles are spent. Easy as: `cProfile.run("phys_in()")` in the main and an `import cProfile` on the top. See what that gives you. Please let us know.

Comment: here are the results

Comment: What happens over time with the file that is read by `read_temp_raw()`? Could it be that it takes longer to get out of the `while ... != 'YES'` loop? Maybe add a counter to that loop and print its value after the while to see how that develops? Could `time.sleep(0.2)` combined with a 1-second-read-time of that file be responsible for the longer running time?

Comment: the file being read is constantly over written by a sensor. i don't know how fast it does this. i am trying the code with out "time.sleep(0.2)". i will let you know the results.

Comment: so after letting it run for 1165.725 seconds.... it made so many threads it couldn't make any more. so i think my log_file() function is making unexpected threads. going to try swapping "threading.Timer(2, log_file).start()" for time.sleep(5) and see what happens.

Comment: I think it worked after 578 seconds the program never slowed down and cpu usage never got past 2% and averaged 1.3%.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi has a small ARM (I think 1.2Ghz) proccessor. It is using up so much of the cpu because there is not much to use. It is like if you have 25hp in a car or 500hp. There is a limit.

Comment: the problem isn't that it takes up a lot of cpu time. the problem is that the amount of the cpu it uses increases overtime.

Comment: Could be a faulty cpu